# Is it a fungus or something else?

Tags: lens, dust, fungus, haze, konica

the following picture is from my dad's Konica Hexanon f/1.7.
Would you call the white layer a **fungus**, **haze**, **dust** or something different?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell from the image you've posted.

Answer (score 4):

If the soft white dots have tiny little tendrils coming from them it's probably, fungus or pollen.

Here's my suspicions...

[image]

Comment: Any balsam separation in there as well?